# How to clear the recyclerview / adapter in searchview for next search android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to search the images and displaying. I am using SearchView to search and recyclerview and adapter to display the item.

It's working for the very first time. Second time when I search, it's displaying the same item. It's not clearing the view to display.

Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
        ImagesViewModel newsViewModel;
        List<Hits> newsArticles;
        List<Hits> articleArrayList;
        ImagesAdapter newsAdapter;
        RecyclerView rvHeadline;
        SearchView searchView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            rvHeadline = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvNews);
            searchView=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
            searchView.setQueryHint("Search Images");
            searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    searchView.setIconified(false);
                }
            });
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    callPixabayImages(query);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    callPixabayImages(newText);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), newText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            articleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 }

 private void callPixabayImages(String query){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ImageApiInterface.PIXABAY_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
                .build();

        ImageApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ImageApiInterface.class);

        Call<MyImages> call = api.getMovieDetails(query);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MyImages>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyImages> call, Response<MyImages> response) {
                Log.e("response","response"+response.code());
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.e("response","response"+response.code());
                    if((response.body() != null ? response.body().getHits() : null) !=null){
                        List<Hits> imagesList = response.body().getHits();
                        articleArrayList.addAll(imagesList);
                      newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyImages> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Error: "+ t.getMessage());
                Log.e("response","response"+t);
            }
        });

    }
 private void setupRecyclerView() {
        if (newsAdapter == null) {
            newsAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(MainActivity.this, articleArrayList);

            rvHeadline.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rvHeadline.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            rvHeadline.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rvHeadline.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        } else {
            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Here where I need to reset to search the new item inorder to avoid to display the previous item. List is not clearing to display the new items.

Here is Adapter class:

```
public class ImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Hits> articles;

    public ImagesAdapter(Context context, List<Hits> articles) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImagesAdapter.NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.images_item, parent, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImagesAdapter.NewsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String image = articles.get(position).getLargeImageURL();
        Log.e("imagestest",image);
        if (image != null) {
            Glide.with(context) //passing context
                    .load(image) //passing your url to load image.
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .placeholder(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.image_not_available)) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                    //.centerCrop()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                    .into(holder.ivNews); //pass imageView reference to appear the image.*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }

    class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView ivNews;
        private NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivNews = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivNews);

        }
    }
}
```

I am clueless where exactly I need to clear the view to fetch the newly searched item.

Trial 1: I tried to clear the list object articleArrayList but it throws crash that adapter size is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clean the**

> articleArrayList

before loading the searched items again.... by executing this line `articleArrayList.clear();`

```
public void onResponse(Call<MyImages> call, Response<MyImages> response) {
                    Log.e("response","response"+response.code());
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.e("response","response"+response.code());
                        if((response.body() != null ? response.body().getHits() : null) !=null){
                            List<Hits> imagesList = response.body().getHits();
```

> ```
>                             articleArrayList.clear();
> ```

```
                          articleArrayList.addAll(imagesList);
                            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I used this but it's not displaying anything in list. No crash nothing but list is displaying nothing.

Comment: then debug every line or log every line to see the exact values and flaw of the code.

Comment: Sorry. Thanks buddy. Working. Got it. Network was down at that time. I didn't noticed. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding generated `imagesList` to the `articleArrayList`, you should be replacing the values.

```
articleArrayList = imagesList;
```